# Set command not writing information in JSON file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord.py

I created a command called "muterole" which has subcommands. Here's how the muterole command looks:

````
@commands.group(aliases=['mr'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def muterole(self, ctx):
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
        await ctx.send("""There are 3 subcommands:
                          \n>>> ```yaml
                          \nmuterole (create/c) <role_name>``` Creates and sets a muterole for this server
                          \n```yaml
                          \nmuterole (set/s) <role_id / role_mention>``` Sets the muterole for this server
                          \n```yaml
                          \nmuterole (remove/r) <role_id / role_mention>``` Removes the set muterole for this server
                   """)
````

Now, I made a "setmr" command which sets the muterole for a server in a json file.

setmr code:

```
@muterole.command(aliases=['smr'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def setmr(self, ctx, *, role : discord.Role = None):
    if not role:
        await ctx.send(">>> **ERROR** : Missing argument - role id / role mention.\nFormat : `muterole (setmr/smr) <role_id/role_mention>`")

    with open('data/muterole.json') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)

    for x in data:
        if x['guild_id'] == ctx.guild.id:
            x['role_id'] = role.id
            x['role_name'] = role.name

            with open("autorole.json", "w") as f:
                json.dump(data, f)
        else:
            new_mr = {
                'role_name':role.name,
                'role_id':role.id,
                'guild_id':ctx.guild.id
            }

            data.append(new_mr)

            with open("autorole.json", "w") as f:
                json.dump(data, f, indent=4)

    await ctx.send("Mute role set successfully.")
```

The problem is that it's not adding ANY information in the json file. Here's how the json file looks:

```json
[]
```

It isn't throwing any errors either.

I made 2 more subcommands "remove" and "create".

Here's how remove command looks:

```
@muterole.command(aliases=['r'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def remove(self, ctx):
    with open('data/muterole.json') as f:
        obj = json.load(f)

    for i in range(len(obj)):
        if obj[i]["guild_id"] == ctx.guild.id:
            obj.pop(i)

            with open('data/muterole.json', 'w') as f:
                json.dump(obj, f)

            await ctx.send(">>> **Success** : Muterole successfully removed.")
            break
        else:
            await ctx.send(">>> **PROCESS ERROR** : You don't have a muterole set for this server.\nTo do so, use this command - `(muterole/mr) (setmr/smr) <role_mention/role_id>`")
            break
```

Here's how create command is coded:

```
@muterole.command(aliases=['c'])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True, manage_channels=True)
async def create(self, ctx, *, role_name = "Muted"):
    mutedRole = await ctx.guild.create_role(name=str(role_name))

    try:
        for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
            await channel.set_permissions(mutedRole, send_messages= False, add_reactions = False)
    except:
        await ctx.send(">>> **PROCESS ERROR** : I might don't have the required permissions to set the muted role permissions for each channel.\nPlease check if I have the required permissions.")

    with open('data/muterole.json') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)

        new_autorole = {
            'role_name':role_name,
            'role_id':mutedRole.id,
            'guild_id':ctx.guild.id
        }

        data.append(new_autorole)

    with open("autorole.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)

    await ctx.send("Mute role created succesfully.")
```

I think all of my code is flawed. I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of iteration is wrong, I assume you want to go over every single dictionary in your list and if you find a dictionary that has the correct guildid in it you add the muterole to it, when you iterate over the whole thing and don't find it you add a new dict to the list. However you do that by iterating the list and add a new element for every element that is not the guild-dict you want. This is unlikely to be what you intended, the adding of a new element should be done after iterating over the whole list and not finding it.

If I were you I'd change the data structure you use right now (list) to a dictionary with the guildids as keys for the data you store per guild, then you can simply check if the guildid is in the keys or not instead of iterating over the while list every time. (note that json doesn't handle integers like guildid as keys, you should look into the object_hook function or convert guildid to strings to find it).

You could also use a variable like `added = False` which you make True if you add the muterole to a dict in the list, if it's false after the iteration you add the new dict

You could also play around with try-else instead of a variable

I'm on mobile so sorry for any spelling mistakes and bad formatting

Note that I only looked at your create code about which you asked a question